# total and group multiple column values in a single query

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I am looking to get a summary of multiple states from the same column.

```
select c.brand
sum amount as total
from charges as c
where c.invoive_id is not null
and c.paid = true
group by c.brand
```

gets me the sum of all completed purchases grouped by brand.
I want to have a separate column in the same query, summed by brand for "c.paid = false"
so I will have:

```
Brand     Total(true)    Total(false)
b_one         25             12
b_two         38             16
```

Comment: What's the database? PostgreSQL, MariaDB, Oracle, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seems to have a simple conditional aggregation statement -

```
SELECT c.brand
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN c.paid = 'true' THEN amount END) as Total(true)
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN c.paid = 'false' THEN amount END) as Total(false)
from charges as c
where c.invoive_id is not null
group by c.brand
```

Comment: Thank you, Ankit. I figured this was a fairly simple request. New to SQl and learning as I go to pull the info I need and build out a few reports. This solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which database you are using so I'll assume PostgreSQL. You can usually use a `CASE` clause to do this. For example:

```
select 
  c.brand,
  sum(case when c.paid then 1 else 0 end) as total_true,
  sum(case when c.paid then 0 else 1 end) as total_false
from charges as c
where c.invoive_id is not null
group by c.brand
```

Answer (score 0):

In databases that support boolean types, you can often do:

```
select c.brand,
       sum(c.paid) as num_true,
       sum(not c.paid) as num_falst
from charges as c
where c.invoive_id is not null
group by c.brand
```